# Hi, I am trying to write a java program that lists all possible ways people can line up on a queue when a user enters a space separated names

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhotoLineups {

// TODO: Write method to create and output all permutations of the list of names.
  public static int index = 0;
  public static void allPermutations(ArrayList nameList, ArrayList permList) {

```
ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
int index;


if(nameList.size() == 0){
  for(int i =0; i < permList.size(); i++){

    System.out.print(permList.get(i) + " ");

  }
  System.out.println();
  //permList.clear();
} else {

  for(index = 0; index < nameList.size(); ++index){

    tempList.add(nameList.get(index));

    nameList = removeFromIndex(nameList, index);
    for(String name: tempList){
      permList.add(name);
    }

    allPermutations(nameList, permList);

    nameList = allParmHelper(nameList, tempList, index);
    permList = removeFromIndex(permList, permList.size() - 1);


  }
}
```

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

```
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> permList = new ArrayList<>();
String name = scnr.nextLine();

String [] names = name.split(" ");

for( int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){

  if(!names[i].equals("-1")){

    nameList.add(names[i]);
  }

}

allPermutations(nameList, permList);

// TODO: Read in a list of names; stop when -1 is read. Then call recursive method.
```

}

public static ArrayList allParmHelper(ArrayList orginStr,ArrayList insertStr, int addLoc) {

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

if(addLoc > 0){
  for(int i = 0; i < addLoc; i++){
    temp.add(orginStr.get(i));
  }
} else {
  temp.add(orginStr.get(addLoc));
}

for(String name: insertStr){
  temp.add(name);
}

for(int i = addLoc; i < orginStr.size(); i++){
  temp.add(orginStr.get(i));
}


return temp;
```

}

public static ArrayList removeFromIndex(ArrayList nameList, int remLoc) {

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

if(remLoc > 0){
  for(int i = 0; i < remLoc; i++){
    temp.add(nameList.get(i));
  }
} else {
  temp.add(nameList.get(remLoc));

}
if(remLoc + 1 < nameList.size()){
  for(int i = remLoc + 1; i < nameList.size(); i++){
    temp.add(nameList.get(i));
  }
}


return temp;
```

}

}

// For instance, if Julia Lucas Mia -1 is 
/** The output is:
 Julia Lucas Mia
 Julia Mia Lucas
 Lucas Julia Mia
 Lucas Mia Julia
 Mia Julia Lucas
 Mia Lucas Julia
 **/

Comment: And what exactly is your question and/or problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being 100% sure what you're asking, here's how you could print all permutations of an ArrayList  of names:
In your main, call: `permute (names, 0, names.size() - 1);`
(Where names is your ArrayList of names)

```
    public static void permute(ArrayList<String> names, int first, int last) 
    {
        if (first == last) 
            System.out.print(getPerm(names) + " "); 
        else { 
            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) { 
                names = swap(names, first, i); 
                permute(names, first + 1, last); 
                names = swap(names, first, i); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static ArrayList<String> swap(ArrayList<String> names, int i, int j) {
        String temp = names.get(i);
        names.set(i, names.get(j));
        names.set(j, temp);

        return names;
    }

    public static String getPerm(ArrayList<String> names) {
        String perm = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            perm += names.get(i);
        }
      return perm;
}

}
```